# Android alert dialog - image on top

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hey I'm trying to put an image above the title in the alert dialog. This is what I'm doing:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog))
        .setView(image)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(btn1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}})
        .setNegativeButton(btn2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}})
        .create();
alertDialog.show();
```

This is the result : 
[image]

And This is what I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

I've also tried it with setIcon but then the image appears on the left of the title and not above.

Comment: Post your activity code here.

Comment: Follow the @Android Weblineindia suggestion.

Comment: The activity is pretty much it. I'm creating the dialog from onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this solution

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setTitle(R.string.my_dialog_title);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.some_icon);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: But then I can't set the theme

Comment: If you want set theme do it in constructor final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);

Comment: Great, but I'm missing one little thing - I removed the headline with dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON); but the headline divider still exist(look like a blue border). When I didn't use custom dialog I could get it with int titleViewId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/ ", null, null);
        TextView title_tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(titleViewId); and change its color. How can I make him disappear now?

Comment: If you want to hide this divider you can try: int divierId = dialog.getContext().getResources()
    .getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
  View divider = dialog.findViewById(divierId);
  divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I ended up putting the image on the layout without using setFeatureDrawableResource (but I did had to use requestWindowFeature   and I did it also for Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE ). Removing the divider didn't work for me but on lollipop it is not seen anyway. Your answer gave me the direction to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom layout in which you can design which you want. Becuase you can not more customization in default existing alert dialog.

Custom Alert dialog you can create with ref url : http://javatechig.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom dialog and inflate that layout for CustomDialog.
You can view Custome dialog here.

[Create Custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042219/how-do-i-create-a-two-color-dialog-like-this/34042951#34042951)